# PHP/AJAX issue inserting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem inserting some data to a mysql database. I have used the same method with other features on the site, and this is the only one causing problems. It's meant to input into 3 field in the database (To, From, Message). As you can see it's a very basic messaging system.

I have the data coming into PHP via AJAX. But the problem is within the INSERT. I have messed around with it for over an hour now - no luck! Here is the code to insert:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (To, From, Message) VALUES('$to','$loggedin','$message') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

And here is the SQL syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'To, From,
>   Message) VALUES('Ryan','Ryan','hhh')'
>   at line 1

I have tried adjusting a lot of things, no luck! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"TO" and "FROM" are reserved keywords, it's not wise to use them as  column names. You have to escape them with a back-tick "`". Try this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (`To`, `From`, `Message`)
```

See the list with reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html